# SQL Server ASP Schema option

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, database-schema

In my Godaddy hosting account I have an option to set up ASP Schema with my SQL Server 2005 database. It describes in very general terms what the option is: "ASP.NET configuration schema contains elements that control how ASP.NET Web applications behave."

Can someone explain to me(or provide a link) in greater detail as to what that does and why I would want to use it?

I've read what a database schema is on wikipedia, but don't understand how one would be different from db to db.

Comment: That was the first thing I tried. The person on the phone doesn't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure but I think it is refering to the ASP.NET Aplication Services that are installed with [aspnet_regsql.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229862(v=VS.100).aspx)

It is the database scheme that handles the [SQL Server providers in ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa478948.).

[image: ASP.NET Schema]